# Binding modifier key to mouse button 4 using KeyRemap4MacBook

Tags: keybindings

I'm wanting to do this so when I'm gaming I can use the mouse button as my modifier "shift" key instead of having to actually hit <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>. This will prevent me from having to take my fingers off of the "1-4" or "Q-R" keys in order to modify them to <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

Some notes:

1. No Mouse Software Available from what I could fine.
2. KeyRemap4MacBook doesn't have the ability to directly let me do it, so I was hoping there might be someone who could help me with the code needed to add it to the program.
3. It doesn't just have to work for this mouse only as I'll essential always use it as a third shift key.
4. I think a global remap might be best.

Comment: I have questions. (1)  Does your mouse have its own software That could maybe do this? Any somewhat recent Logitech gaming mouse should. (2) [Keyremap4MacBook or Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en)? (3) Should it remap the key for that mouse only? (4) Should it remap the button for a specific application? -- You can answer these by editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how much difference there is between KeyRemap4MacBook and Karabiner <sub><sup>(minus Karabiner Elements)</sup></sub>, so I can't guarantee that this will work on older versions. KeyRemap4MacBook got a name change to "Karabiner" in 2014 I believe, so some of the documentation may not apply to it anymore.

<sup><sub>I only have access to mac with Sierra, so I couldn't test it in any version.</sub></sup>

1. Follow the instructions on [how to add custom settings](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html.en#privatexml)

   - Get back to this after you've completed `step 3`.
2. Ignore `step 4` and replace the contents of private.xml with:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>

  <item>
    <name>Mouse Button 4 to Shift</name>
    <identifier>MouseBtn4ToShift</identifier>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
        PointingButton::BUTTON4,
        KeyCode::SHIFT_L
    </autogen>
  </item>

</root>
```

---

3. Continue the instructions on [how to add custom settings](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html.en#privatexml) at `step 5`.

> If you're not 100% sure that it's actually button number 4 that you're pressing, [you can use the EventViewer to check](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html.en#eventviewer).

---

Just incase someone is interested:

- [Filter: Specify application](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en#appdef)
- [Filter: Specify device](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en#devicedef)

Comment: Hey @Joonas, yes we're talking about the same program. I just tried one of their built in ones and it didn't work. Tried your and got the same thing. Is there a spot I'm suppose to "activate them other than just checking the box?

Comment: Hmm... No. That should do it.  What if you test it using the EventViewer?  It will show that shift key is triggered when you press that mouse button... If it worked. What I'm thinking is that it is possible that something in the game could prevent it from working, so better test if the built in event viewer sees the changed keys. You may also want to make sure that it supports your OS version and that you've added and checked it in `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy (top right) > Accessbility (left)`. Click the lock and enter admin pass to edit. It may already be there...

Comment: I think the issue is it needs another update to work on my OS right now. That explains why no part of the program works. Do you know any other programs that may work?

Comment: I don't. Why don't you update? Or check what your OS version is and download the appropriate version of [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en)? It lists the supported OS X version in each download button... Except for Karabiner elements, which works on Sierra (10.12). You can check your OS version in the  Apple menu in the top left, and by going to the About section. Should say "Version X" at the top of the About window.

Comment: Just got Karabiner Elements, I didn't know I could download it since it wasn't finished. I'm looking for a place to add my own code now- does it have to be done in terminal?

Comment: Well that's the thing. Sierra had some changes that affected Karabiner so much that it didn't work anymore and had to be rebuild from ground up. I had to downgrade my work mac to El Capitan so I could use the normal Karabiner version. For now Karabiner Elements is a very stripped down version of Karabiner and only does simple key changes. If it doesn't have an option in the application menu to change mouse button 4 to something else, then you're out of luck. I don't know if there is any other way... Other than downgrading to a version of OS X that supports the normal Karabiner.

Comment: @RonnieLeeBoothIII I just realized that I was too focused on Karabiner. Since you only need a mouse key changed, there are other mouse only options: [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html), [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/index.html),  [Smooze](https://smooze.co/). None of these are free though.

Comment: Also… This is a bit of a sales speech, but… I personally use Logitech MMO mouse (G600) on Windows and Mac and the Logitech Gaming Software works well enough on both (I've not used it for gaming on mac).  This mouse has 12 buttons on the side and also "G-shift", which you can assign to any button on the mouse. It is basically a second layout that is activated while the G-shift button is pressed. I absolutely love the fact that I can have number keys in the mouse.

Comment: I use the mouse for FPS games as well. Typically I use that “extra” mouse button on the right as melee in games, but is also be excellent for the G-shift. [Screenshot of the basic layout in the software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSevn.png) --- [Screenshot of the G-shift layout in the software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Ekx.png). The side buttons do have a bit of a learning curve,  but once you get used to them, they are awesome. I never use the number keys on my keyboard for gaming. --- Just something to consider. Not the cheapest mouse.